# Converting a forEach loop to a Future.forEach loop in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I try to convert a `.forEach` loop to a `Future.forEach` loop in flutter to wait for the loop. The element I want to loop is a snapshot from a Firebase Realtime Database.

**My function looks like this:**

```
Future<User> getUserByUid(String uid) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =
        await databaseRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).once();

    List user = List();

    dataSnapshot.value.forEach((key, value) async {
      User entry = await User.fromJson(value);
      await entry.setId(key);

      user.add(entry);
    });

    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      return user[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I tried different ways, but I don't get the function to work.

**First Try:**

```
Future<User> getUserByUid(String uid) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =
        await databaseRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).once();

    List user = List();

    await Future.forEach(dataSnapshot.value, (element) {
      print(element);
    });

    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      return user[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

**Second Try:**

```
Future<User> getUserByUid(String uid) async {
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot =
        await databaseRef.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).once();

    List user = List();

    for (var u in dataSnapshot.value) {
      print(u);
    }

    if (user.isNotEmpty) {
      return user[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Error:

> Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'

For all tries I get the same error. But the `.forEach` example above works.

Additional question: In `.forEach` I get also the `key` variable. Is this also available in Future.forEach in some way?

Comment: it says that `dataSnapshot.value` is not `Itearable` since it is a `Map` - if you want `Iterable` use `Map.key` / `Map.values` / `Map.entries`

Comment: So simple.... it works. Thank you! Is there also the possibility to get the `key` of these? The key saves the uid and would be important to read..

Comment: sorry not `Map.key` - it should be `Map.keys` of course

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to loop over a map, but (as the error says) a [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/Map-class.html) isn't iterable. You **can** loop over the keys of the map though:

```
for (var key in dataSnapshot.value.keys) {
  print(dataSnapshot.value[key]);
}
```